# Comparison of two estimators

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

> Let $X$ be distributed as a Poisson($\lambda$) such that it's density is given by
>
> $$\mathbb{P}_\lambda(X=x) =\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$$
>
> Compare the following estimators of $g(\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}$,
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> T1 &= e^{-\bar X}\\
> T2 &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nI(Xi=0)}{n}
> \end{align}
> $$

I am studying consistency bias and stuff like that, but I do know how to set up  this exercise to compare these 2 estimators
Can someone just give an hint ?
it would be very appreciate

Comment: Two things to think about, among others:  (A) $\bar X$ is an unbiased maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$ using a sufficient statistic;  (B) $P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: MLE it is unbiased for a poisson because is equal to $\bar X$ that is equal to the expected value , for a poisson $E[X]$ = $\lambda$ so it is unbiased  Does this means that $T1$ is also unbiased?

Comment: No: $T_1$ is biased, as usually happens with an non-linear function of a unbiased estimator

Comment: i computed that $\bar X$ is distribuited as a normal ($\lambda$; $\frac{\lambda}{n})$ Then I do not understand how to apply Deltha method  should I apply Deltha method to compare variance of this 2 estimators?

Comment: From CLT we have $\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\lambda\right)\approx \mathcal{N}(0,\lambda)$. Now take $g(x)=\exp(-x)$ in delta method to get the asymptotic variance of $\exp\left(-\bar{X}\right)$

Comment: so the asymptotic variance of exp($\bar X)$ is equal to $(g'(x))^2$  $Var(\bar X)$ = $e^{-2\lambda}$ * $\frac{\lambda}{n}$ is this the asymptotic variance of the first estimator?